# how i can center all item with margin?

Tags: html, css

how r u guys 
can any one help me to center all item with margin
in this code

*Html COde*

```html
<div class="se">
  <div> <img class="seimg" src="images/we.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="sep">
    <h2> Who we are?</h2>
    <p>We have been operating for over 30 years and are Members of The Federation of Master Builders. We work on projects big and small from small residential extensions to full house. We are so happy with this theme. Everyday it make our lives better.
    </p>
    <span>We care about environment.</span>
    <span>We are trusted by hundreds of clients.</span>
    <span>Social media loves us!</span>
    <span>This list is super easy to create</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`text-align`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP) CSS property

Comment: What your tried? Your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center text, use text-align: center;
To center image horizontally best to use flex-box, just 3 lines of code.
This centers everything, no matter the image dimensions.

```
.se {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.sep {
    text-align: center;
}
```